# How do I send the JavaScript Array to the Controller from Ajax

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

Cannot get object values in the controller from the ajax post.

I have a jQuery data table with the first column being checkbox's and I need to return the selected row ids to the controller. I can get everything I need but it is always null in the controller.

```
 Model:
    public class Values
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
    }


View JS & Ajax on button click:
    function SubAll() {
        var values = [];

    $('#timesheet').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function (index, rowId) {
            //this is the current checkbox
            var temp = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');

            if (String(temp) === String("undefined")) {
                //skip; it is the select all box
            }
            else {
                //push to array
                values.push(temp);
            }
        });

        console.log(values);
        var data = { ID: values };
        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("ApproveAllTimesheets", "Admin")",
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus) {
                if (xhr.status == 401) { alert("Session Expired!"); window.location = "/Account"; }
                else {
                    alert('Content load failed!', "info");
                }
            }
        });
    };


Controller:
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public void ApproveAllTimesheets(List<Values> value)
    {}
```

On button click the array 'values' gets filled with the  id if a box was selected (works fine), then it is turned into an object 'data' to match the method signature and model and stringify'd. When the breakpoint is hit on the controller method the values are never there. What am I missing?

```
    **UPDATE:**
    function SubAll() {
        var values = [];

        $('#timesheet').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function (index, rowId) {
            //this is the current checkbox
            var temp = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');

            if (String(temp) === String("undefined")) {
                //skip; it is the select all box
            }
            else {
                //push to array
                values.push({ Id: temp });
            }
        });

        console.log(values);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/ApproveAllTimesheets",
            type: "POST",
            data: values,
            dataType: "html",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus) {
                if (xhr.status == 401) { alert("Session Expired!"); window.location = "/Account"; }
                else {
                    alert('Content load failed!', "info");
                }
            }
        });
    };

    **Method Signature:**
    public IActionResult ApproveAllTimesheets( List<Value> values)

    **Class**
     public class Value
     {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
     }
```

**UPDATE #3**

```
    Model:
    public class Value
    {
        public string TimeId { get; set; }
    }

    Ajax:
    function SubAll() {
        //var selectedValues = $('#timesheet').DataTable().column(0).checkboxes.selected().toArray();
        var dataJSON = { TimeId: "test" };

        console.log(dataJSON);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/ApproveAllTimesheets",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(dataJSON),
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus) {
                if (xhr.status == 401) { alert("Session Expired!"); window.location = "/Account"; }
                else {
                    alert('Content load failed!', "info");
                }
            }
        });
      };

    Controller:
    public ActionResult ApproveAllTimesheets([FromBody]Value information)
```

Comment: so what is your current problem since you have add comment after new update ?

Comment: I have been able to get this to work with a class and simple type. Now I need help extending it to work with multiple values. Update #3 will be my current working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my Update #3 is working and now I have a different issue so I will post a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your JSON

```
{ <-- This here is the start of your object
    "id": 1;
}
```

This would need to get bound to a Model

```
class AnyModel {
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

If you have a list in JSON

```
{
  [
    ...Some objects
  ]
}
```

You would need to accept a model of in your controller

```
class AnyModel {
   public List<SomeOtherModel> ListObject {get; set;}
}
```

**Update**

You want to store the list of 'Values' in another model.

```
class Value {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
}

class ValueContainer {
   public List<Value> Values {get; set;}
}
```

Now you want to bind your JSON to your ValueContainer object. When you send JSON you need the `[FromBody]` for the JSON to get bound to your Model.

```
public IActionResult ApproveAllTimesheets([FromBody] ValueContainer values) {}
```

**Update 2**

Apologies looking through your JS code (old one) a little bit closer you should be using the following structure:

```
class ValueContainer {
   public List<Guid> Id {get; set;}
}
```

`List<Guid>` is your values array which you bind to `id` in your JSON object. Controller stays the same.

```
public IActionResult ApproveAllTimesheets([FromBody] ValueContainer values) {}
```

Comment: I changed it to create it strigify'd like this: {"value":[{"ID":"1"},{"ID":"2"},{"ID":"3"}]}
public IActionResult ApproveAllTimesheets(List<Value> value) - Controller
Class Value has 1 property public Guid ID { get; set; }

Still no data!!!

Comment: I always get a 415 no matter what.

Comment: @Michael remove `dataType` and `contentType` from your ajax method

Answer (score 0):

You should insert the ids like javascript normal objects :

```
 values.push({
            ID: "d88b44e4-1009-47d6-9f2f-f675dca89fe8",

        });
```

Code below is for your reference  :

```
function SubAll() {
    var values = [];
    values.push({
        ID: "d88b44e4-1009-47d6-9f2f-f675dca89fe6",

    });
    values.push({
        ID: "d88b44e4-1009-47d6-9f2f-f675dca89fe7",

    });
    values.push({
        ID: "d88b44e4-1009-47d6-9f2f-f675dca89fe8",

    });


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/ApproveAllTimesheets",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(values),
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus) {
            if (xhr.status == 401) { alert("Session Expired!"); window.location = "/Account"; }
            else {
                alert('Content load failed!', "info");
            }
        }
    });

};
```

Controller :

```
public void ApproveAllTimesheets([FromBody]List<Values> value)
{

}
```

Model :

```
public class Values
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I made those changes and I get a 415 unsupported media type with the [FromBody] tag. If I remove the tag it goes into the method but the collection is empty. I feel we are close but missing something small.